# I want USA only ip addresses, how do i set that up?

Tags: exit-relays, support, help

Would like a step by step explanation on how i can set my Tor to only use USA ip/exit nodes, thank you....

Answer (score 11):

Look for `Data/Tor/torrc` file inside your Tor Browser Bundle directory.
Add the following line to your `torrc` file:

> ExitNodes {us}

That's all.

Comment: If set like this, will all nodes in a circuit are in US? Maybe should like this: ExitNodes {us}
EntryNodes {us}
HSLayer2Nodes {us}
HSLayer3Nodes {us}