# Google Play Store detects wrong IP address when using Tor

Tags: help, google, exit-relays

I use Tor when accessing the Play Store. I have Tor to use US exit nodes only and I've confirmed by looking up my IP while using Tor that I indeed have US IPs. However, when accessing Play Store, Play Store seems to think my IP is from somewhere else -- sometimes it shows prices in euros, sometimes in British pounds, or non-US dollars. What is going on? Why am I not getting US version of Play Store even though I have US IP addresses?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

My configuration includes

ExitNodes {us}

StrictNodes 1

ExcludeNodes {all CC except US}

UPDATE2:

For example, with an exit node with IP address of 204.17.56.42, Play Store is showing me the wrong price for https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a22neko.noisep&hl=en -- it isn't showing US price of $5.00. On the other hand, exit node with IP address of 162.218.68.130 is showing the proper US$5.00. What the hell is going on?

Comment: Have you configured Tor to only use US exit nodes? https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1533/88

Comment: Please show your actual configuration for evaluation.

Comment: @JensKubieziel Yes, I have that configured.

Comment: @Roya The only custom item I have in my torrc file is ExitNodes {us}. As mentioned in my post, when I check my IP address while using Tor, it shows up as a valid US IP. I've even checked it with Tor's Atlas. However, Play Store seems to detect it from a different country for some reason.

Comment: Dear PlayStoreUser, keep in mind that at any moment you may utilize several circuits, each for a separate purpose. At this point Atlas will not all of them. Look at this question for reference: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/when-i-use-tor-i-occasionally-get-two-different-ip-address-simultaneously

Comment: @Roya Would this still apply if I used an external IP check (e.g. http://whatsmyipaddress.org) to check my IP and it showed up as US? Shouldn't Play Store's website see the same US IP address? And if this is the issue, do you know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I modified my torrc to exclude all countries except US (see update above) and the same problem is happening.

Comment: It's not only the IP address that can be used to get your location/language/country or whatever similar. Your device has a configured language, a gsm/utms provider etc. Google is very good in mining and analzing data, keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes it would apply if you used an external IP check (e.g. whatsmyipaddress.org) to check your IP and it showed up as US. To see how many IP addresses you are using, you may use ip-check.info it will give you some clue as of what IP addresses you are using.